# I am trying to pass json_encode from PHP into JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript

I am trying to pass arrays from PHP into javascript by using json_encode

but when i alert the values i just see "Object object etc"

when i var_dump it i see the actual arrays but its not showing them in the alert

Any help would be appreciated

Regards

this is the var_dump

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(19) "3.0268"
    ["postcode"]=>
    string(137) "hello"
  }
}

array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(19) "3.0268070455319E+17"
    ["postcode"]=>
    string(137) "ECMWF continues its flip-flopping, still a temp drop next week & #snow risk but then no rise, http://t.co/tBlg9Ihs #ukweather #uksnow"
```

}
Code

```
<?php

 $con =  mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
    mysql_select_db('test');

   $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM address");

$arr = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $arr[] = $row; 

}

?>

<script>

var test = <?php echo json_encode($arr); ?>;
alert(test);

</script>
```

Comment: What is the printed output?

Comment: That's the expected output. Everything is fine. The *default string representation* of an object is `"[object Object]"`. Use `console.log` to inspect variables.

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/loop-through-javascript-object

Comment: You should use the console, but if you really need an `alert`, use  `alert(JSON.stringify(test));`

Comment: Why did you add the `var_dump`? Isn't Daniel's answer clear enough?

Comment: Mathletics asked for it, i understand it now just making it clear for when people view this question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`alert` will call `toString()` on what is passed to it. You might want `console.log`. `test` is an object and that is what objects print in `alert` by default.

Example:

```
alert({a:1,b:2}) // => [object Object]
({a:1,b:2}).toString() // => "[object Object]"
```

Comment: @Hashey100 http://jsfiddle.net/UpBEx/ Be sure to have your console open